How to build android cuttlefish 0.9.31?
I tried to follow the official document https://source.android.com/docs/devices/cuttlefish/get-started to build cuttlefish, but when I execute tools/buildutils/build_packages.sh I got the following error.
cd cvd && bazel build --linkopt="-Wl,--build-id=sha1" cuttlefish:cvd --spawn_strategy=local
2024/08/30 20:16:20 could not resolve the version 'latest' to an actual version number: unable to determine latest version: could not list Bazel versions in GCS bucket: could not list GCS objects at https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bazel/o?delimiter=/: could not fetch https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bazel/o?delimiter=/: Get "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bazel/o?delimiter=/": dial tcp 172.217.167.74:443: i/o timeout
make[1]: *** [debian/rules:24: override_dh_auto_build] Error 1

I checked that bazel has already been installed on my ubuntu, what can I do now? And when I use curl to access the url https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bazel/o?delimiter=/ I can get the correct content, which means my network connection is OK.
bazel --version
bazel 7.3.1


After days of debug I give up using proxy. It seems that BAZEL does not recognize my proxy configuration correctly, so I have to setup a VPN to build the project.
